Is it safe to pass MapState to downstream in Flink?
Suppose we have a DataStream and it is possiable to attach a MapState to each String element while passing it to downstream. Like:
ds.keyBy(s -> s.hashCode() % 10)
.process(new KeyedProcessFuncion<Integer, String, Tuple2<String, MapState<String,String>>>(){
  transient MapState<String,String> map;
  public void open(Configuration cfg) {
    map = this.getRuntimeContext().getMapState(new MapStateDescription<>("demo", String.class, String.class));
  }
  public void processElement(String in, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple2<String, MapState<String,String>>> out) throws Exception {
    if(map.get("key") == null){
      map.put("key", "val");
    }
    out.collect(new Tuple2<>(in, map));
  }
})
.keyBy(t -> t.f0.hashCode() % 10)
.process(/* the demo MapState can be accessed here*/)

The codes above works but the problem is: Is it safe to access the MapState in downstream passed by upstream?

No, that's not possible. Flink scopes the state it manages to individual operators. For example, in your job, the second process function could be running on a different machine, which would make sharing the state a bad idea.
This is unrelated to your question, but given how the MapState is being used, perhaps ValueState is all that's actually needed. ValueState stores a value for each distinct key, while MapState stores a map for each key (which is effectively a nested map).

So, if I collect the data in MapState into a HashMap object and pass it to collector in first process, would it be better? Since I just test the codes in local, which did not make the "different machine" problem.

Efforts to work against Flink's compute model often end badly, due to faulty assumptions about how the Flink runtime works. Rather than fighting against Flink's design, usually there's a better way to achieve the desired goal. Why don't you ask another question, this time outlining the use case and explaining why sharing state between operators seems like a good solution. Maybe then we can suggest an alternative.

In my case, I want attach some business parameters (update in low frequency) to the data, and pass them together to downstreams, so that the downstream can get them without worry about how to get the params. I've tried broadcast stream, I polling the params from some data source (may be every 10 mins), but it seems need an extrodinary close method to shutdown the broadcast stream. But when I use state, it is no need to worry about that.

Rather than sharing the params as state, you could send them in a stream. Using a broadcast stream for that sounds like a good option -- not sure what you mean by "need an extraordinary close method to shutdown the broadcast stream", that doesn't sounds right.

No, because the map (if you're using RocksDB) isn't an in-memory representation of the state. Also, what are you actually storing in the MapState? Note that when your KeyedProcessFunction is called, the state is already set up to be for the current key, so you don't need to store the key in the map.
